# non homogenous wave equation with non homogenous boundary and initial conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am studying for an exam and am stumped by this because everything is non homogenous. The question is to solve for $u$,

\begin{align*}
u_{tt} &= u_{xx} + q, 0 < x < 1, t>0\\
u(0,t) &= 0, t>0\\
u(1,t) &= sint, t>0\\
u(x,0) &= u_t(x,0) = 0, 0<x<1
\end{align*}

I have first tired to get rid of the non homogenous boundary condition $u(1,t) = sint$ by saying defining $w$ to be,

$w(x,t) = u(x,t) - xsint$

so the equation becomes,

\begin{align*}
w_{tt} &= w_{xx} + q - xcost\\
w(0,1) &= 0\\
w(1,t) &= 0\\
w_t(x,0) &= -x\\
w(x,0) &= x(1-x)\\
\end{align*}

I am confused about how to proceed, can anyone help?